# ResNet 34 training with custom dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, residuals, residual-networks

I am a beginner in Neural Networks and wanted to implement ResNet34 for a pet project at my workplace. Due to confidentiality issues, I do not want to use ImageNet trained weights.

I have a dataset of around 10000 images which I can use to train my dataset. Can you suggest if that is possible without overfitting. I can use data augmentation for additional data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how confidentiality makes transfer learning an issue. That does not make sense to me and i would strongly consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd want a bit more images in order to train your model effectively. I've managed to train a couple of ResNet-50 models on around 10000 MR Images from scratch, without much problem.

However, what I was trying to solve was a relatively easy task. If you want to train your model on a more *generic* task, you might encounter a few issues. On the other hand, because of the strict format of MRIs, I couldn't augment my images to a large degree.

Comment: I am trying to classify documents into around 10 categories. Do you think it would work ?

Comment: And each document is represented as an image?